# Python: String formatting when when writing command line instruction

Tags: python, string, arguments, subprocess, call

I have a task where I have to run a bunch of simulations with slightly different parameters each time. I'd like to write a Python script to automate this but I'm having an issue.

To simplify the description, I essentially have `N` simulations called from the command line, each with a different set of parameters, and I'd like the script to execute them one by one. Imagine that to run a simulation I would write `execute_simulation...` to the command line where the `...` stands for the parameters of the given simulation. This is what my script looks like:

```
from subprocess import call

<code>

for i in range(0, N):
    call('execute_simulation_%s' % ( parameters[i]))
```

However, I always get error messages when calling the script. Can anyone suggest why this might be the case?

Comment: What's the error message? [`call`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) expects a list of args, not a string (unless you use `shell=True`, which you should avoid).

Comment: WHAT error messages?

Comment: What are the simulations files exactly? Does your `parameters[]` also contain the file extension? `call('ca%s.exe' % 'lc')` is working for me (Win7).

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you had included the error messages but I'll try to help you anyway.

The `call` function expects a sequence of strings not a single string (although the `Popen` documentation states that they are converted to a string on Windows, so it may working in specific cases).

Also, in the example code you gave, you did `call('execute_simulation_%s' % ( parameters[i]))`. If `parameters[i]` is not a string but a list, tuple, generator or then `str` will be called on that object which means you get something like `execute_simulation ['arg0', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4']`. This is probably not what you want. You can call `' '.join` on the sequence to get something like `execute_simulation arg0 arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4`.

With that being said, I assume that `parameters` a list  of lists containing the arguments for each call. Then you could just do

```
args = [f'arg{i}' for i in range(5)]
parameters = [args for i in range(5)]

for args in parameters:
    call(('execute_simulation', *args))
```

Also, consider using `subprocess.run`, since it is recommended to use in Python 3.5+ code (it works just like `call`).
I hope this works in your case.